# How to save an object containing a list of objects to database in ASP.NET MVC with EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core-2.1

I know this question exists ( I literally copy pasted it) but its answer is unclear and doesnt work for me I have a model which Ive tried adding to a database, it consist of complex datatypes and lists and the database has stored  it totally not the way I intended
this is my class im trying to store:
'''
`

```
enter code here
`[Table("Recipes")]
    public class Recipe
    {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Descrption")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Tags RTags { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public List<Instruction> Instructions { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

'''

this is my class ingredient:
'''`

```
public class Ingredient
    {
        [ForeignKey("recipe Id")]
        public int Id  { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }

        public MeasurementType MeasurementUnit { get; set; }
    }`
 `
```

`
'''
here is what it is stored like in the db:
as you can see in the image it has only saved an object with id, title, description, RTagsid and image

[database without lists or complex data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmdVX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can store changes to a child object like following:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
   ctx.Recipe.Attach(recipe);// Parent
    ctx.Entry(recipe).State = EntityState.Added;  
    ctx.Ingredient.Attach(ingredient);// Child
    ctx.Entry(ingredient).State = EntityState.Added;  // or EntityState.Modified
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: im a beginning beginner :) so do you mind please explaining what you just did? and how does it help me and most importantly where should I add the code

Comment: Above code you have to put where you are performing DB operations. In code as per yhour questions you want to store Child object as well for that I add `ctx.Ingredient.Attach(ingredient);// Child
    ctx.Entry(ingredient).State = EntityState.Added;` this 2 lines which helps you to add the data in both the tables after performing `ctx.SaveChanges();`